# Angular *NgFor iterate strings in an array to Table TD tags

Tags: java, json, angular

I have created an angular page which retrieves JSON data from a backend.

The Json output is formatted like

```
fields  
0   "count"
1   "Date"
2   "Status"
rows    
0   "["2","2019-11-21","Operate"]"
1   "["3","2019-12-12","Maintain"]"
________________________________________________

{
    "fields":
        ["count","Date","Status"],
    "rows":
        [
            "["2","2019-11-21","Operate"]",
            "["3","2019-12-12","Maintain"]"
        ],
    "id":
        0
}
```

I want to create a table on my frontend using the values from fields as the headers and the values from rows as the cells. For example

```
_____________________________
| count |   Date   | Status |
|---------------------------|
|   2   |2019-11-21| Operate|
|   3   |2019-12-12|Maintain|
-----------------------------
```

However when calling the data I am getting these results

```
| count                       |   Date   | Status |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|["2","2019-11-21","Operate"] |          |        |
|["3","2019-12-12","Maintain"]|          |        |
---------------------------------------------------
```

My html code for the table is as follows

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-hover" *ngIf="appDetail?.fields">
    <thead>
        <th *ngFor="let field of appDetail.fields" class="table-header">{{field}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of appDetail.rows">
            <td *ngFor="let item of row">{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My Model

```
export class AppDetail {
    public fields: string[];
    public rows: string[][];
}
```

My Component

```
public getSealData() {

    this.sealidService.getSplunkData(this.idValue).subscribe(data => {
      this.appDetail = data as AppDetail;

      console.log(data.fields);
      console.log(data.rows);

    })

  }
```

**EDIT**
Now that I am iterating between the  and  I am getting the following error message in console

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object of type String
```

I am assuming that related to my model?

**EDIT**
Turns out I am not getting an array of arrays, but an array of strings. It looks like there was some decoding going on but the actual JSON looks more like this

```
"fields": 
    ["count","Date","Status"],
 "rows": 
    ["[\"2\",\"2019-11-21\",\"Operate\"]", "[\"3\",\"2019-12-12\",\"Maintain\"]"],
```

So the errors I am getting is due to the string values not being iterate-able. 
Console.log output console.log(data.rows)

```
0: "["2","2019-11-21","Operate"]"
1: "["2","2019-12-02","Maintain"]"
```

RESOLVED - I will have to work with the owner of the backend data in order to get the proper format in which the response Saurabh's answer will be applicable.

Comment: Show us the actual JSON instead of this weird representation. And why are you using ngFor on a container instead of on tr itself? Why are there two AngularJS ng-repeat in the middle of this Angular markup? Use Angular ngFor. Not AngularJS ng-repeat.

Comment: @JBNizet added JSON and removed the repeats. Sorry was trying all different things and left some garbage behind

Comment: Now you're not iterating to generate the tr anymore. The structure you had was correct, but you used ng-repeat instead of ngFor. You need to iterate on the rows to generate the `tr`s, and in each row, iterate on the elements to generate the `td`s

Comment: @JBNizet Look better?

Comment: Do you have control over the backend? Also, can you paste the *exact* response you get by doing a `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @Sudosu0 it is  "["2","2019-11-21","Operate"]" a string not an array, thats the problem, fix this from backend

Comment: @NicholasK updated with colsole.log data. I do not own the backend but i will work with the team that does to see if they can make the proper changes!

Comment: Rather than manipulating *this* string response, make the backend return a JSON so that working with it becomes much easier.

Comment: the `rows` array is an array of string that are stringified arrays.  You can just parse each string. Something like... `data.rows = data.rows.map(e => JSON.parse(e))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evufwk)**

you can do like this: 
Iterate on rows, row element itself are array than again iterate on those to render `td`

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let row of appDetail.rows">
      <td *ngFor="let item of row">{{item}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Why the ng-containers. they're useless. Just put the ngFor on the tr and the td.

Comment: @JBNizet When trying to use NgFor on the TR and TD tags, you get errors stating that ngFor is not valid for that type of tag

Comment: @Saurabh I followed your example as well as modified my code above. Please see the error message output

Comment: @Sudosu0 - I don't see the error messages (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zq8mpm?file=src/app/app.component.html)).

Comment: @JBNizet ya you are right, in this there is no need to use ng-container, i have updating the answer

Comment: @Sudosu0 i have check it its seem it is working fine

Comment: You are right, it is working. However it doesnt solve my issue... I am sorry for the bad information. See edited question

Comment: Marked as answer, as it is the answer for what was originally asked and will be my answer moving forward. Thank you all!